# getting namespace Alexa insted of Alexa.PowerController on v3 smart home skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, home-automation

I am trying to switch on a Alexa powercontroller device using Alexa android app.
but each lambda event I get this.

```
{
    "directive": {
        "header": {
            "namespace": "Alexa",
            "name": "ReportState",
            "payloadVersion": "3",
            "messageId": "c985c301-1ae8-4013-8a5d-c975e9ddf31f",
            "correlationToken": "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"
        },
        "endpoint": {
            "scope": {
                "type": "BearerToken",
                "token": "eyJraWQiOiI2SXp5OTROeGUxVXloUWlIampLVmpNaTJqTUZhbGtBcnFTS3ZtYUoyQ3JRPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiI3ZWMxMTZjZi01MjUzLTQyMjctYTE4NC0wYTM0YTIzZDhlNWUiLCJldmVudF9pZCI6ImJhNWI2NDI3LWZhYTItNDhhMC04NjE0LTM1Y2NhNjMyMWVmNiIsInRva2VuX3VzZSI6ImFjY2VzcyIsInNjb3BlIjoib3BlbmlkIHByb2ZpbGUgZW1haWwiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE2MTUyOTIxNTksImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOlwvXC9jb2duaXRvLWlkcC51cy1lYXN0LTIuYW1hem9uYXdzLmNvbVwvdXMtZWFzdC0yXzJ4ZHJMZWdIMyIsImV4cCI6MTYxNTM3NjkwOCwiaWF0IjoxNjE1MzczMzA4LCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoyLCJqdGkiOiIyYmYzZWNjMS01NGVhLTQwM2ItYjhmOS0yNDdlYjFmNjdjNDIiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiI2bWpzcWNmbzZoaThpdnRoMmtlMWplY3UwciIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiN2VjMTE2Y2YtNTI1My00MjI3LWExODQtMGEzNGEyM2Q4ZTVlIn0.N0VpPX-nkFO6fbddMyZeF7zutVR9YiBO1hK6H5jVo4rNMwYbXhM_DH6l5nhwsuSmhhtzJjjwBCvB2hm2yJ9ZgYuIQPRttoPZZVsiVF_YQoMsOA08W1C3vJTXjIn5n1-NwHunegtiMHcqpMwvErJOg_fKE388dos2y-38rDmTTTwxKilSL1uU6NLoTcUbaPdKRlUkExqaaP_mGITGy7pviNk-tgCPQXdh3pf8kw9l1Jk_eWQDLT0lrAtUoWOhVtML5JKgGzysOU963mKQLgU-fcsWnrCwftrL5dGA57wJUzm9O5LIWwahzpdispv5KisIQxk0QcV7Qan27xnv8XD8VA"
            },
            "endpointId": "endpoint-001",
            "cookie": {
                "detail1": "For simplicity, this is the only appliance",
                "detail2": "that has some values in the additionalApplianceDetails"
            }
        },
        "payload": {}
    }
}
```

Look at the namespace field it shows only shows Alexa instead of Alexa.PowerController
[here is the official v3 sample](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-powercontroller.html).

I can still done this by using name field but I doubt that while using some Alexa devices it will back as on the documentation even though it show v3.

How do i deal with this situation.
Using node 14.x.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the [ReportState](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/state-reporting-for-a-smart-home-skill.html#reportstate-directive) directive. It's not instead of PowerController. It's an additional directive. You suppose to send a [StateReport](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/state-reporting-for-a-smart-home-skill.html#statereport-event) as a response.

Normally this directive is sent every few seconds when mobile app is open, so if your device's state changed (e.g. for physical interaction with a device), it will appear correctly in the app.